# Correct asserting with Espresso i have item listed in ListView

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I want to test with `Espresso` android testing framework that all expected titles are shown in ListView.

I'm having Activity with ListView that shows files in the directory. Each ListView item is an `Item`object:

```
/**
 * Item
 */
static class Item {
    private String title;
    private IFileInfo fileInfo;
    private int imageResourceId;

    public Item(String title, IFileInfo fileInfo, int imageResourceId) 
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.fileInfo = fileInfo;
        this.imageResourceId = imageResourceId;
    }

    public IFileInfo getFileInfo() {
        return fileInfo;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public int getImageResourceId() {
        return imageResourceId;
    }
}
```

The holder just sets title and image for the item:

```
/**
 * Adapter
 */
private class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public Adapter(Context context, List<Item> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.file_dialog_row, null);
            convertView.setTag(new Holder(convertView));
        }

        Item item = getItem(position);
        Holder holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.getTitleView().setText(item.getTitle());
        holder.getTitleView().setTextColor(itemColorStateList);
        holder.getImageView().setImageResource(item.getImageResourceId());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:id="@+id/fdrowimage"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="3dp" android:paddingLeft="3dp"/>

<TextView android:text="@+id/fdrowtext" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fdrowtext"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fdrowimage" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/fdrowimage"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="19dp"/>
```

Originally i wanted to assert that item with text "N" is listed (i'm having a list of `Item` objects and i want to assert for each it's shown).

To check that it actually works i've checked the test should fail for some actually not shown item title, but for some reason the tests succeeds:

```
onData(allOf(is(instanceOf(Item.class)), withText("someNotListedItemTitle"), isDisplayed()));
```

Here is full test code:

```
...

@Test
public void testShowFiles() throws IOException {
    List<File> files = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        File tmpFile = new File(rootFilesFolder, generateUniqueString());
        files.add(tmpFile);

        if (i % 2 == 0)
            FileUtils.touch(tmpFile); // create file
        else
            FileUtils.forceMkdir(tmpFile); // create folder
    }

    // add not shown for sure in ListView item
    File notExistingListed = new File(rootFilesFolder, generateUniqueString());
    files.add(notExistingListed);

    // activity creates ListView that shows file name for each file in TextView with @+id/fdrowtext
    startActivityForPath(rootFilesFolder);

    for (File eachFile : files) {
        // should fail for `notExistingListed`
        onData(anyOf(is(instanceOf(Item.class)), withText(eachFile.getName()), isDisplayed())); 
    }
}
```

What is correct assertion with Espresso?
Should i create custom Matcher for my item?

Answer (score 0):

I have some experience with `Espresso` test framework. 
But I used `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView` and there are some functionality in this framework concerning `RecyclerView` like:

```
onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view)).perform(
            actionOnItemAtPosition(itemPosition, swipeLeft()));
```

And also I did the custom matcher for `RecyclerView` items, looks like:

```
onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.recycler_view).
                atPositionOnView(itemPosition, R.id.child_view)).
                check(matches(withText("Element 1")));
```

So I can assert value from any view on some position in `RecyclerView`

Please, let me know if you need some more information concerning it.

Comment: there is a significant difference between `ListView` and `RecyclerView` as noted here: https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/lists/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to workaround it with `withText` instead of `onData` but it seems to be a dirty trick:

```
for (File eachFile : files) {
    onView(withText(eachFile.getName())).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

What is correct assertion with `onData`?